# How to fix bad decoding without losing other characters?

Tags: python, character-encoding

My day to day hobby is to crawl websites and gather a lot of data.
Recently, I have observed a case when some captured data was malformed `10% Off Orders of Ã’£100` and contained an accent letter (`Ã`) in combination with some right single quotation mark (`’`).

I have tried to encoding it using `ascii` with ignore, but I'm losing the pound(`£`) symbol.

```py
>>>'10% Off Orders of Ã’£100'.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
'10% Off Orders of 100'
```

Also, tried with `latin-1` too, but after decoding it got a new character instead of `£` -> `ã`.

```
>>> '10% Off Orders of Ã’£100'.encode('latin', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
'10% Off Orders of ã100'
```

So, how can I fix this encoding and keep the pound or other currency symbol?

Comment: You don't happen to have the source-html from where you encountered the malformed string?

Comment: The meta charset of html page was `utf-8`.

Comment: Yeah, well that didn't really answer my question. Did you have the source or not? It most probably is something wrong either with how you're parsing the site, or there is something in the HTML that is creating some characters that your script is not expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could sanitize the string by removing all the non-ASCII characters, except the £ symbol.

Here's an example of a function that does that:

```
def remove_non_ascii(s):
    return "".join(i for i in s if any([ord(i)<128, ord(i) in [163]]))
```

It preserves all the printable ASCII characters and the pound sign (163).

```
>>> example = '10% Off Orders of Ã’£100'
>>> remove_non_ascii(example)
'10% Off Orders of £100'
>>>
```

Comment: Nice way of cleaning. You just gave me an ideea.

Comment: In my case, `''.join(i for i in text if ord(i)<190)` will be enough. Thank you again for your answer.